# Using Sed to pull out base URL of full website

Tags: windows, sed

I'm looking to cat a file containing something like this:

```
    http://www.site1.com/d23bdbd0fbc517d34, r N 4
    https://www.site2.com/file/d23bdbd0fbc517d34, X
    http://www.site3.com/file/d23bdbd0fbc517d34
    https://www.site4.edu/site/d23bdbd0fbc517d34
```

and I need use sed to get this kind of output:

```
    www.site1.com
    www.site2.com
    www.site3.com
    www.site4.edu
```

Help!  I can't get it fully working right.  Technically I'm using sed.exe for Windows but it's probably very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat file.txt
    http://www.site1.com/d23bdbd0fbc517d34, r N 4
    https://www.site2.com/file/d23bdbd0fbc517d34, X
    http://www.site3.com/file/d23bdbd0fbc517d34
    https://www.site4.edu/site/d23bdbd0fbc517d34
$ sed -r 's@.*//([^ /]+).*@\1@g' file.txt
www.site1.com
www.site2.com
www.site3.com
www.site4.edu
```

If you don't have `-r` switch :

```
sed 's@.*//\([^ /]\+\)[/ ].*@\1@g' file.txt
```

Moreover, under [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) IIRC, use double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

So maybe :

```
sed.exe "s@.*//\([^ /]\+\)[/ ].*@\1@g" file.txt
```

Comment: THANKS! Crap this works but I just noticed lines that have things like this:  http://www.site.com   X Y Z.  basically no "/" on the end of the URL.

Comment: thanks this mainly works but still have issues with the output because .com/something works but .com something  still prints the something.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant is:

```
sed '\#.*www[.]\([^/]*\).*# s::\1:'
```

will display

```
site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
site4.edu
```

tested with

```
@ThinkPad-T420:~$ sed --version 
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

Comment: this one assumes that *www* is in the url

Comment: he can add alone :www.\1 instead of \1. or move '\(' before www.